# SQL query returnin previous weeks

Tags: sql, oracle

I need the SQL query which will return previous 10 weeks in format 2017W03 for given week in the sam format.

So for week given in format 2017W05 this query should return:

```
2017W05
2017W04
2017W03
2017W02
2017W01
2016W52
2016W51
2016W50
2016W49
2016W48
```

Comment: Is the prior year always assumed to have 52 weeks?

Comment: Not, of course! Otherwise I wouldn't ask this Q! Silly thing is that date `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01.01.2017','DD.MM.YYYY'),'YYYYIW')='201752'`

Comment: Poblem here is that week format (like `IW`) cannot be used as input in TO_DATE() function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified solution, taking advantage of the fact that January 4 always falls in the first ISO week of its year. (January 1 may fall in the last ISO week of the prior year, and that would lead to complications.)

An earlier version (which can be reviewed by clicking on the "edited ..." link below the Answer) did not take advantage of this observation.

Also, credit to tbone - to get the proper ISO year/week combination, we must use the format model component **`IYYY`** for the year (in `TO_CHAR`), rather than **`YYYY`**.

```
with
     input ( str ) as (
       select '2017W05' from dual
     )
select     to_char(to_date(substr(str, 1, 4)||'0104', 'yyyymmdd') +
                     7 * (to_number(substr(str, 6)) - level), 'iyyy"W"iw') as result
from       input
connect by level <= 10
;



RESULT
-------
2017W05
2017W04
2017W03
2017W02
2017W01
2016W52
2016W51
2016W50
2016W49
2016W48
```

Comment: Woof, gove me some time to study it! I figured out something else: `SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR('2017W05',1,4)||'0101','YYYYMMDD')+(SUBSTR('2017W05',6)-LEVEL)*7+1,'YYYY"W"IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10` but I have to check if it works for other years.

Comment: @sbrbot - It seems your solution is similar to mine, you just wrote everything in a single formula. I could do the same thing, but I wrote it the way I did so that, at each step, you can see the result. (Remove the comma at the end of any CTE and instead type `select * from <cte_name>` to see what it generates.) When you are done inspecting the code, you can rewrite my solution in a single, long formula.

Comment: @sbrbot - Connecting the year to January 1 will cause problems in some years, because January 1 may fall in the last ISO week of the prior year. (That is why I use July 1 - it could be any other date that is guaranteed to fall in an ISO week of the current year.) However, thinking about this issue, I realized that January 4 will always fall in the first ISO week of the current year. This, then, allows for a simpler solution. I will work on it and post it in my Answer above.

Comment: I think we should probably use IYYY instead of YYYY (in the to_char) per the docs (I updated my answer too).  This would handle situation where 20170101 is actually 2016W52 for example.

Comment: using IYYY should also allow us to use 0101 instead of 0104 (check me on that ;)

Comment: @tbone  - Err... you are right about needing to use IYYY in the output. I am not sure how that helps with the input though (using 0101 instead of 0104).

Comment: Since the OP wants string as input, I'll vote for this answer, don't have any clever way of converting to date other than what you did here :)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the output you listed:

```
select TO_CHAR(to_date('20170201','YYYYMMDD')-(7*(level-1)),'IYYY"W"IW') 
from dual
connect by level <= 10
```

Output:

```
2017W05
2017W04
2017W03
2017W02
2017W01
2016W52
2016W51
2016W50
2016W49
2016W48
```

Starting with the arbitrary date of Feb 1st 2017

Comment: The date is not "arbitrary" - this depends on the date being in the fifth ISO week of the year - and that did happen in 2017, but it is not guaranteed to be true every year. In addition, this hardcodes the 05; presumably the OP wants an answer where the input may be any year, any week.

Comment: @mathguy I see, so we're starting with a string not a date.  Not sure what you mean about hardcoding 05

Comment: I assume "for given week in the same format" would indicate that, yes. The OP's attempt (in a comment to my Answer) suggests the same thing.

Comment: The OP's problem is EXACTLY that, given a year and an ISO week number, there is no simple way to generate a date (for example, midnight on the Monday of that week) for that year/ISO week combination.

Comment: In my post I said for "given week", so this SQL will be part of function where week and range number will be given as input parameters and it should return range of weeks. Input week will be week as string in IYYY"W"IW format and range INTEGER. So week 2017W05 (od date 20170201 in that week) cannot be hardcoded.

Comment: Hi sbrbot It wasn't hardcoded for the approach to work, it was just used as an example.  If you have a specific function spec you wanted, it probably would have avoided confusion if you listed that in your post. (input parameters, return values).  Anyway, if your function takes a date, use my approach, if it takes a string, use @mathguy approach.  Both similar.  Hope it helps.